# BeautifulSoup -- Prevent Tag From Automatically Closing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup is choking on parsing the following code:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<img src="#" alt="Click Here >" border="0" />')
>>> soup.prettify()
'<img src="#" alt="Click Here &gt;" />\n" border="0" />\n'
```

I should also note, I have no control over the input html.  There are many different variations of the text/attributes so I want to avoid using Regex.

Anyone have a suggestion for stopping BeautifulSoup from automatically closing the img tag when it runs into the ">" symbol?

Edit 1:  I have found [this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Customizing%20the%20Parser) in the documentation.  Could I control how BeautifulSoup parses the IMG tag?

Edit 2: I solved my problem.  Before I called BS, I did did a text replace

```
text.replace('>"','&gt;"')
```

Comment: Could you encode those entities in attributes first?

Comment: @alex:  I'm not sure there's an easy method.  That would involve parsing the html with another library (before parsing with BeautifulSoup) and finding the symbol inside the attribute.

Comment: @Ryan How can I use replace() if I am using url to parse instead of string as you typed above?

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup4 has been updated to be context aware and has since solved this issue. If you update to the latest version of BeautifulSoup4 it will ignore the `>` tag when enclosed in quotes.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<img src="#" alt="Click Here >" border="0" />')
print(soup.img.attrs)
# {'src': '#', 'alt': 'Click Here >', 'border': '0'}
soup.prettify()
# '<img src="#" alt="Click Here &gt;" />\n" border="0" />\n'
```

The example shows that the `alt` attribute correctly has the `>` character, and the `border` attribute has been recognised.